# Realizing a small signal inverter

Tags: inverting-amplifier

I have a small signal Vs at the input and I want small signal -Vs at the output using an inverter. How can I do it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffebUq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the circuit of the inverter and It has a small signal Vout= -gm*R*Vs
where gm is the gain. If I can put R=1/gm, I get the output I want. But, that doesn't work in the circuit. Is there any other modification I can do to the circuit to get an inverting stage?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mosfets are not properly biased.

The models you are using in the schematic are power mosfet, they can withstand some 100V Vds, with only 3V across each device they never really turn on. Try running a frequency sweep, not only this circuit does not invert the signal, it even attenuates it.

You can fix it in two ways:

- use small signal mosfets, something with a 600mV threshold should do
- power your circuit with at the very minimum 12V, 20V is better. Change Vbias accordingly

Simulators are powerful but you need to use them with a grain of salt. And always, *always*, ***always*** read the datasheet. Really, just do it.